# Please suggest best practices for using Virtualenv in Pycharm on Windows

Tags: python, windows, pycharm, virtualenv

I’m starting to learn Python using PyCharm IDE on windows. I have a specific question about where to start adding/ creating python files/ classes.

I installed Python 3.5 and installed PyCharm Community. Created a project first and then created a virtualenv. I can therefore switch between 'Python Interpreters'. But, when I open PyCharm project, I see a folder structure and I can’t make a decision where to start creating code files. I've added screenshot as reference.

[image]

Where to start adding creating code file packages? And, is this the right way of creating virtualenv?

I'd also appreciate if you could please suggest any related best practices, especially regarding using virtualenv in this scenario.

Answer (score 2):

Create the virtualenv while creating the project.  Click the gear icon to the right of the interpreter box at the new project dialog box.  Choose "Create VirtuanEnv"

Then you can right click the project name and add a python file.

[image: Create VirtualEnv]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Typically when developing python code on windows using PyCharm, I create a subfolder in my User directory (C:/Users/Vasili/virtualenvs/), where I place all of my future virtual environments.

When creating a new project, I create a new virtualenv in that folder and set it as the interpreter for the project. PyCharm will use that venv every time you open that project. It will also activate it whenever you use the inline terminal within PyCharm so you can run executables such as nosetests, if you have it installed in the project virtualenv.

As for general project structure, python is fairly informal when it comes to this, but there are some standards that you could try to adhere to, such as:

- creating a `setup.py` file with your project metadata and other data to allow uploading the project to pypi, or even building RPMS.
- a `requirements.txt` file with packages that pip must install for the project to work
- A tests folder with your unit tests, fixtures and so on
- The actual package itself, named after your project, with a dunder init script (`__init__.py`) inside, to signify that it is a package
- An open source license
- A readme, or documentation that can generate HTML docs with sphinx
- Anything else you think would help people use your software.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using community edition, you will have some limitations of the features.

I would suggest you to create virtual env from terminal/command prompt.
This is the folder structure which I follow for development while using Pycharm:

```
C:\workspace\<virtual_env>
C:\workspace\<project_name>
```

Add the whole workspace folder to your Pycharm as project.

In order to create and activate virtual env in windows refer the following:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/windows/